# JasperReports - stretch report band to fit all columns in one row

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am developing report which is not going to be put on paper - just export it into xlsx format.

I have ability to set width of band with data to high number, but i would like to have ability to make this band stretch horizontally to fit all cells from one results row in single line. How I can do that?

PS: I am using iReport to build jrxml file, but I am comfortable with directly editing the jrxml file.

Comment: when you use ireport and created jrxml you can paste all the columns in a row right. That is how i remember it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Dynamic Jasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/). I think the example [here](http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-create-a-clean-excel-report/) may solve your problem. It can create the you the jrxml file if you don't want to have the DJ code in your application.